# Using FeatherLight to show a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, featherlight.js

I am using the featherlight lightbox plugin to show the contents of a DIV when a button is clicked.

Here is my button:

```
<INPUT id="mileageButton" <cfif #get_trips.recordcount# NEQ 0>style="color:red; font-weight: bold;"</cfif> class="mileage" Type="BUTTON" VALUE="Mileage" onClick="$('##mileage-modal-open').trigger('click');"> <a id="mileage-modal-open" href="##" data-featherlight="##mileage" ></a>
```

Here is my DIV:

```
<div id="mileage" style="display:none;">
</div>
```

The problem I am having is that I do not want to DIV to be visible until the button is clicked, so I set the display attribute to 'none'. However it stays hidden all the time and consequently my lightbox is empty.

How can I have the attribute changed to 'block' when I click the button but back to 'none' when I close the lightbox?

Comment: Should work, most demos use that technique

Comment: I can open the lightbox no problem but the DIV is not shown because I hide it with CSS otherwise the contents of the DIV are always shown. Regardless if I press the button or not. What is the workaround for that?

Answer (score 3):

Keep your DIV visible and put it inside another one that is hidden. That way, when featherlight opens it, it will show up.

Comment: your solution worked like a charm. a little bit weird that we have to do this kind of bypass.. but it did the job. I wonder if the guys at FeatherLight fixed this by now (didn't see any other methood)

Comment: Glad it helped. You could also try some other things, like using the featherlight class and CSS to force your div showing when it's inside it. Or even using featherlight binds afterContent and beforeClose to change your content visibility. But the option I provided is the simpler one that I always use. ;)